# Friendly URL and remove php prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have this in my htaccess

```
Options +MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ dash.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ dash.php?p=$1
```

and im trying to make this url:

```
http://mywebdomain.com/dash.php?p=dash&mode=All
```

look like this:

```
http://mywebdomain.com/dash/All
```

Is there a way to do this?

and also if i had for example this:

```
http://mywebdomain.com/user/manage.php?p=manage&mode=Me
```

how could i get that to look like this:

```
http://mywebdomain.com/user/manage/Me
```

I have successfully managed to get the .php extension removed by the **Options +Multiviews** command but i am struggling trying to work out why it wont work for the re-write of the extended parts of the url.

Thanks for any help in advance too :)
Jonny

Answer (score 0):

With `MultiViews` on, you do not need `Rewrite` to accomplish this.

since `dash.php` file exist in document root, Apache will pass requests to `/dash/anything` to `dash.php`, and that php script can parse the URI (found in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`) to check what was the full uri called.

same goes for `/user/manage.php` ...